# Is a vibrating belt not effective in reducing tummy fat?

Tags: exercise-equipment, bellyfat

In my gym, there is a vibrating belt present. I haven't seen anyone using that so far in the past two months. Is it not effective in reducing tummy fat? How is this equipment used, for what duration, and what is its effectiveness? Should it be used or not?

Answer (score 15):

Vibrating belts are worthless. A crock. A sham. A hoax. A useless, insulting, silly doohickey that should be shunned by all right-thinking people.

It's proper use is to be smashed underfoot or with a sturdy implement such as an ax or crowbar. Destroy it.

Instead, look into proper diet (such as Primal or Paleo eating) and exercise (such as barbells, sprints, and sports).

Comment: Hi ,Dave Liepmann, Thanks for putting  forward the reality of such belts. I think this question must be voted as it could be eye opener for those who would be thinking of using it.

Comment: +1 for "smashing with sturdy implement" at least you'd get a good workout that way.

Comment: @jaydee ...hahaha well said...

Comment: To be fair, if you get *two* people in to one of those shakey-belt machines, things start to get interesting.

Comment: -1 It's a hoax because you say so? Why should I believe random guy on the internet? This answer is empty.

Comment: @michael Can you find evidence that it works? Better yet, post your own answer with evidence either way. Burden of proof is on the claim that it's effective. Evidence of absence is what they call difficult.

Comment: Whoever invented it is a marketing genius.  Finding the "get ripped fast" method is the new farce in our society.  So many idiots went out and bought them believing that simply sitting will deliver results.  I liked watching those commercials but I loved seeing the reaction from certain people.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann As of this comment, you have 9 upvotes for an answer with absolutely no content. It's not about me providing a better answer. It's about the fact that this community seems to value opinion and conjecture. I've said it before: how is this forum any better than Yahoo Answers?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann But since you asked. Here's 5 minutes on google scholar (But who needs science when we have intuition, right?): Delecluse, C., et al. (2003). Strength increase after whole body vibration 
compared with resistance training. Med Sci Sports Exer. 35:1033-41.

Comment: Delecluse, C., et al. (2003). Strength increase after whole body vibration 
compared with resistance training. Med Sci Sports Exer. 35:1033-41.

Comment: Delecluse, C., et al. (2003). Strength increase after whole body vibration 
compared with resistance training. Med Sci Sports Exer. 35:1033-41.

Comment: Di Loreto, C., et al. (2004). Effects of whole-body-vibration exercise on the 
endocrine system of healthy men. J Endocrin Invest. 27:323-27.

Comment: @michael We're better than Y!A because we enforce quality in grammar and we try to cultivate a community of experts. However, we're not skeptics.SE, which has a reference requirement (which has its problems) on all answers. Extracting your references would make a fine answer. But in this case the question was a quickie, and so I thought a simple quickie answer was sufficient. However, you're absolutely right that a better answer would explain the science and/or have references.

Comment: @michael It seems that those studies are about vibration platforms, not belts. Regardless, I found their results (and those of some similar studies) either unconvincing or pointing to zero or very little effect.